# Is it a valid metric to divide mean squared error (MSE) by the range of the values in the original vector?

Tags: mse

Say I have a vector of values `v`, and I have an estimate of those values, say I call this vector `e`. In order to compute the goodness of the estimate, I compute `mean([v-e]^2)`, which is MSE, and to get a reasonable error between 0 and 1, I divide this number by the difference `max(v)-min(v)`. This looks intuitively correct, but I am wondering if this is statistically valid. I was thinking this would be what is called normalized MSE (NMSE), but my Google search for NMSE does not look like to agree that. Could someone tell me whether what I am doing makes sense, and what is its difference from NMSE?

Comment: Why would you think dividing by the range of $v$ would cause your measure to lie within $(0, 1)$?  It's easy to come up with counterexamples to this.

Comment: I agree that this measure may not always be in `[0,1]`, but for my case, it is. My main point is that the result of such a normalization sounds more intuitive as an error, that's, .4 sounds better as an error rather than 400, when the range of my values in `v` is `[0,1000]`.